# Button onclick changes text more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick, typing

So i made this button, and i made the description text change from

```
 {description}
```

to "No..." upon clicking. This is what i made:

```
<!-- 
 function changeText(txt){
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = txt;
 }

 // -->
 </script>
 <p> <b id='name'>{description}</b>. </p>
 <input type='image' onclick='changeText("No...")' src='http://i.imgur.com/4y6bzH9.png'
 style="margin-left:540px; margin-bottom:20px; position:absolute; outline:none;"/>
 <br /><br />
 <!--v comp-->
 <!-- 



 /*<body> </html>
```

I tried to make the description text change another time upon clicking another one time on the same button, so i tried adding another onClick, to make the description text change to "Another text" the next time you click the button.

```
<!-- 
 function changeText(txt){
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = txt;
 }

 // -->
 </script>
 <p> <b id='name'>{description}</b>. </p>
 <input type='image' onclick='changeText("No...")';
  onclick='changeText("Another text")';src='http://i.imgur.com/4y6bzH9.png'
 style="margin-left:540px; margin-bottom:20px; position:absolute; outline:none;"/>
 <br /><br />
 <!--v comp-->
 <!-- 



 /*<body> </html>
```

I tested it, and it didn't work. Please, does anyone know what i did wrong? I was also wondering if there was a way to make the text have a typing effect, if possible?

Comment: Please give some feedback on below answer. Is it working?

Comment: @PatrickGeyer Where are you rushing?

Comment: @nicael Nowhere... I just dislike it when it takes an age to get a reply on a question that is easily findable on the web. In some cases it just shows lack of effort.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i was away. it didn't work though, i've already googled it and most of them are "change button text onclick" or "more than one event upon one onClick". but thanks so much for helping!! :D

Answer (score 0):

What you're currently doing overwrites the previous on click event. Try this:

```
    function changeText(txt){
        document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = txt;
        document.getElementById('name').onclick = function(){
           changeTxt('Another text...');
        };
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that because the last onclick callback will override the previous.

You have to improve your javascript  => http://jsbin.com/zeyogufo/3/edit

Comment: it looks like it might work, but do i put the javascript code after </style> and before </head> on tumblr?

Comment: search "</body>" and insert your javascript code just before the tag. (Don’t forget to add <script type=”text/JavaScript> and </script> codes between the JS code.) ;)

Comment: done, but it's not changing the text. i tried it here on /http://yosougay.tumblr.com/ (please don't mind the name, it's a reference to persona 4, i f you know it)

Comment: You can't use jquery like that on tumblr
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576419/why-is-jquery-not-working-on-my-tumblr ;)

Comment: Please, Frédéric, always post your code here, Jsbin is ok for demonstration purposes, but answers should be self-contained. Thanks!