# Button onclick more than once, different text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

So i made this button, and i made the description text change from

```
{description}
```

to "No..." upon clicking. This is what i made:

```
function changeText(txt){
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<p> 
    <b id='name'>{description}</b>.
</p>
<input type='image' 
    onclick='changeText("No...")' 
    src='http://i.imgur.com/4y6bzH9.png' 
    style="margin-left: 540px; margin-bottom: 20px; position: absolute; outline: none;"/>
```

If you want, you can view what i did on /http://yosougay.tumblr.com/

I tried to make the description text change another time upon clicking another one time on the same button, so i tried adding another onClick, to make the description text change to "Another text" the next time you click the button.

```
function changeText(txt){
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<p> 
    <b id='name'>{description}</b>. 
</p>
<input type='image' 
    onclick='changeText("No...")';
    onclick='changeText("Another text")';src='http://i.imgur.com/4y6bzH9.png'
    style="margin-left: 540px; margin-bottom: 20px; position: absolute; outline: none;" />
```

I tested it, and it didn't work. Please, is it possible to make a JavaScript button that changes the text to different texts every time it is clicked?

So far, I've only been able two make the text change once.

Comment: Why you need to change the text each time ??

Comment: from where you are getting new text? or you toggling between "No.." and "Another text"?

Comment: @jenz i need it because i want to make it seem like a dialogue box where the text changes every time you click the button. I've only succeded in making the text change once though, and upon one click.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar sorry im not really sure what you're asking :/

Comment: @Yuki [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/7E7yN/) - this is my version. Something like that makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Yuki, I have answered your question and where I am swapping description between only "No.." and "Another Text". I am asking this is what you want or you want a new description every time, if yes then  how you are getting the new description?

Comment: I'm trying to make it have a new description every time the button is clicked, like this jsfiddle by @Mark Rijsmus, http://jsfiddle.net/54pp2/3/

Comment: it won't work on the page though

Comment: @Ruddy thank you! I'm going to try it now!

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/54pp2/2/

```
<input id="click" type="button" value="click" />
<label id="test">Test</label>


$(document).ready(function () {
    var textArray = [];
    textArray[0] = 'test 1';    
    textArray[1] = 'test 2';    
    textArray[2] = 'test 3';    
    textArray[3] = 'test 4';    

    var idx = 0;
    $('input#click').on('click', function(){
        idx++;
        var newidx = idx % textArray.length;
        $('label#test').text(textArray[newidx]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think this is the most flexible approach, so far

Comment: Nice! Well that is a matter of preference, i prefer readability :). But still nice edit.

Comment: me too, and it looks great!! but then i tried it on here : /http://yosougay.tumblr.com/ and it doesn't seem to work though..

Comment: O well, keep in mind that you need the jquery library included for this solution.

Comment: @MarkRijsmus oh do u mean that this has to be put before the javascript code in my theme? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576419/why-is-jquery-not-working-on-my-tumblr

Comment: Yes, in the head tag of the page. <head></head>

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.

You can only bind one click listener that way. Duplicating the attribute onclick will only override the first one, not provide two click listeners.

What you want to do is to handle the "different text every time" in you single onclick listener.

```
<script> 
  var txts = ["first", "second", "third"]
  var counter = 0;
  function changeText() {
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = txts[counter%3];
    counter++;
  }
</script>

<p> 
    <b id='name'>{description}</b>.
</p>
<input type='image' 
       onclick='changeText()' 
       src='http://i.imgur.com/4y6bzH9.png' 
       style="margin-left: 540px;
              margin-bottom: 20px;
              position: absolute; 
              outline:  none;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you want

```
<script>
<!-- 

 $(document).ready(function(){

     var textarray ={"No...","Another Text"};
     var count = 0;
     $('input[type="image"]').click(function(){
         $('#name').text(textarray[count]);
         count = count==0?1:0;
     });
 });

 // -->
 </script>
 <p> <b id='name'>{description}</b>. </p>
 <input type='image' onclick='changeText("No...")' src='http://i.imgur.com/4y6bzH9.png'
 style="margin-left:540px; margin-bottom:20px; position:absolute; outline:none;"/>
 <br /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of how many times the button has been clicked from inside javascript.

```
<script>
var clicked = 0;
function changeText(){
    if (clicked == 0) {
         document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = "No...";
    }
    else if (clicked == 1) {
         document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = "Another text";
    }
    clicked++;
}
</script>
```

Notice how I removed the argument from changeText() as well.

Answer (score 0):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5PHvH/)**

My suggestion is to change the onclick to `onclick='changeText()'`.

Store the texts in an array, and use a count property on the element. This will also move to the first text and repeat, on the third click.

```
var texts = [
    'No',
    'Another text'
];

function changeText(){
    var elem  = document.getElementById('name');
    if(typeof elem.count == 'undefined'){
        elem.count = 0;   
    } else {
        elem.count++;   
    }

    if(elem.count == texts.length){
        elem.count = 0;   
    }

    elem.innerHTML = texts[elem.count];
}
```