# Tumblr: jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I'm developing a Tumblr theme, but I have a problem with jquery.
When I use this bunch code outside of Tumbl it work like a charm, but when I use it on Tumblr nothing happen. How can I make it work on Tumblr too?
How you can see in the fiddle I want to add the class .smaller to the header when the article reach the top of the window.
thanks,
Filippo

```js
// resize the header to small size
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
  if
      ($(document).scrollTop() > $(window).height()){
    $("header").addClass("smaller");
   updateSliderMargin();
  }
  else
  {
   $("header").removeClass("smaller");
   updateSliderMargin();
  }
 });
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
header.smaller {
    height: 50px;
}
header.smaller ul {
    display: none;
}
article {
    position: relative;
    top: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
    min-height: 1000px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>This is the Header</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>list 1</li>
            <li>list 2</li>
            <li>list 3</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <article>
        <p>This is the Article</p>
    </article>
</body>
```

**Fiddle Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/z3cqkt9a/

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: yes, this: ReferenceError: updateSliderMargin is not defined
 

updateSliderMargin();

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576419/why-is-jquery-not-working-on-my-tumblr

Comment: The error message is a huge clue. Where / how have you included the function `updateSliderMargin()`. Its not present in either the code above of the **Fiddle Demo**.

Comment: If you remove the references to updateSlideMargin() the code does work, I expect that is a function from an old library, although I cannot trace anything on google. I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/z3cqkt9a/1/. I made the css change apply when the scroll offset is more than 10 pixels.